# Permute of an Array requires Size+1 causing null in Output, Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

First of all, before anything else... yes, I know using an ArrayList would be much easier than using an array.  I get that, but for the project I need to learn how to do it with just an array using recursion.

Okay so In my code below I am outputting all permutations of an array, but unless I make the size of my array the user inputted size +1 i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.  This causes the array to have one value of null, which is outputted as a space causing issues with my output.

Why is it requiring me to set the size to be the inputted size plus one?  and how can I fix this?  Thank you in advance.

```
package permutearray;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Ra'kiir
*/
public class PermuteArray {

public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("How many characters in the permute array:  ");
    int p = keyboard.nextInt();
    char[] permuteArray = new char[p+1];
    System.out.print("Enter a line of " + p + " characters:  ");
    String charString = keyboard.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        permuteArray[i] = charString.charAt(i);
    }
    permutation(permuteArray, 0, p);

} //End main method

private static void permutation(char[] permuteArray, int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {

    if (lastIndex - firstIndex == 1) {
        print(permuteArray);
        swap(firstIndex, lastIndex, permuteArray);
        print(permuteArray);
        //restore the order in string array
        swap(firstIndex, lastIndex, permuteArray);

    } else {
        //swap String at firstindex with all the next Strings in the array
        for (int i = firstIndex, j = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++, j++) {
            swap(firstIndex, firstIndex + j, permuteArray);
            //With current initial String(s) find combinations for rest of the strings 
            permutation(permuteArray, firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
            //restore the order in string array
            swap(firstIndex, firstIndex + j, permuteArray);
        }
    }

} //End swap method

private static void swap(int firstIndex, int lastIndex, char[] permuteArray) {
    char temp = permuteArray[lastIndex];
    permuteArray[lastIndex] = permuteArray[firstIndex];
    permuteArray[firstIndex] = temp;
}

private static void print(char[] permuteArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < permuteArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(permuteArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
} //End print method

} //End of Main Class
```

Comment: `i <= lastIndex`, should probably be `i < lastIndex`. Otherwise, on the first level of recursion, `i` will iterate up to `p`, which is out of bounds of the array since arrays are 0-based.

Comment: I think I know why the size of the array has to be the number of characters plus one. The last index is reserved for NULL character. When you iterate through the array, you will do so WHILE CHAR != NULL, instead of N number of times, where N is the size of the array.

Comment: @Jon you are correct about that being an issue, but it still doesn't solve the problem.  You are correct that was an error though.  A careless type-o on my part.

Comment: @hfontanez The problem is you cannot check if an entry in an array of type char is null, because it gives you an error saying that char and null are incomparable types.  You'd think they would let you do this, but apparently not.  It was a good idea though.

Comment: @Ra'kiir, you are obviously doing something wrong because a primitive `char` is initialized to null character '\u0000' (unicode 0). Therefore, you can indeed compare the current value of your `char` variable to see if it is equal to this value.  You are probably comparing it to `null` which is a reserved keyword to be used with object references, not primitive data types.

Comment: @hfontanez In any case, that's not the issue. If you reduce the size of the array to just `p`, you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in the swap method, well after the data has read in successfully.

Comment: The error is that `firstIndex + j` will be greater than the length of your array on the last iteration of your loop. Add a check to make sure that it is less than `permuteArray.length` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Jon, I was answering his question: "Why is it requiring me to set the size to be the inputted size plus one?" If you read my first comment was that I believe the "plus 1" location is reserved to hold a null character.  So, you are mistaken; my answer is indeed addressing one of his questions.